# Authorize.Net Paypal Express PHP API: Issue with transaction not updating in Authorize.Net , nor capturing correct amount

Tags: php, paypal, authorize.net

We've implemented the Paypal Express API through Authorize.Net  in PHP (https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/paypal.html). It was finished over a year ago, and has been working fine. What we realized recently, is that the when the Paypal authorization is updated in step 2 "Authorization Only, Continued", it is not updated in Authorize.Net . When a capture takes place, it only captures the original amount, despite Paypal having the correct, updated amount.

Here is our flow (following the Authorize.Net/Paypal API instructions):

1. We send a request to Authorize.Net/Paypal to create a transaction. Inside is the total cost of goods.
2. Paypal returns a secure link, onto which we redirect the user
3. Paypal redirects the user back to us with a token. We use the token to get shipping data for the user and to get the authorization/transaction ID.
4. We calculate tax based on shipping data and send the user to a confirm page for review.
5. When the user submits, we send the second authorization request (Authorization Only, Continued), as documented, using the gateway transaction ID to update the transaction with the new amount, etc.

Now the problem is, Authorize.Net still has the original amount (without the tax). When we run a capture on this transaction via the same API, for some reason it only captures the original amount, not the amount with the tax. We're making tons of transactions now, and not receiving the tax dollars for any of them.

Here is the same transaction in Paypal and Authorize.Net. Paypal's screen shows the authorization at $120, and the update at $130.xx with shipping.

[image: Paypal Interface]

And Authorize.Net shows it successfully captured at $120.

[image: Authorize.Net Interface]

These are the same transaction, and we're only using the Authorize.Net Paypal Express API. How is Authorize.Net not getting the update? Why is it not capturing the full amount?

Comment: I have concluded this is a bug in the Authorize.Net Paypal Express API. Paypal shows the correct, updated transaction amount, but authorize.net doesn't. So when I capture using the Authorize.Net API, I'm stuck with the pre-tax amount. As Paypal support and others have suggested, I tried to capture with a higher amount than was authorized, and Authorize.Net returned an error: "The amount requested for settlement cannot be greater than the original amount authorized." which is quite logical.

Answer (score 0):

> When we run a capture on this transaction via the same API, for some reason it only captures the original amount, not the amount with the tax.

You need to either:

- Capture the **second** authorization, not the original transaction. This should be the correct solution.
- Send a capture request that includes the details of the **new amounts** you are capturing.

Comment: Thanks Preston. 
The docs don't outline a way to send a new amount. I'll try your first bullet first.

Comment: OK. I just tried the first bullet, but I learned that when you pass in a reference transaction ID, the second authorization uses the same transaction ID as the first. So there is no way to capture the "second" authorization. Here's right from the API response using print_r() "[transId:private] => 62315491947\n [refTransID:private] => 62315491947\n"

Comment: Hmm. I would ask the Authorize.Net team for support then. As a direct PayPal API matter what I described is how it works, but you're limited by what the Authorize.Net proxy exposes to you / how they want you to do things